# how to automatically add non-specified dimensions to a design table

Tags: solidworks

I would like to create a boss using a spline with many points, then scale it using a design table.  The catch is that I don't want to manually set dimensions (in x,y, and z) for each of the points of the spline, for adding to the table.  I would just like -all- the dimensions of all the sketches to be automatically added, if I so desire.  does solidworks have  this functionality?  I can understand that this  might result in a night-mare, but then again, it might not be so hard to group the dimensions by x, y, and z for each point on the spline..

Comment: Define coordinates rather than dimensions, and use curve through points?

Comment: (you can calculate the coordinates using equations in an excel spreadsheet)

Comment: ..I'm looking to create something organic, the trunk and branches of a tree, so I suppose I could use superpositions of waves as the equations..   you're right, of  course..  slick..